# HTML5 body background CSS with triangular shapes

Tags: html, css, background

I am working on a new ASP.Net Core website. The UX/UI team has come up with a background design that uses triangular shapes similar to the attached image. The design actually has slight gradient within the 2 different colours themselves. Is it possible to add a background for the body that accomplishes something like this. ie

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient...
}
```

Over 60% of our users are on mobile. However we also need support Internet Explorer 11 (but nothing earlier). We could of course simply use a plain colour for browsers that don't support whatever css we ultimately end up using.

[image: Proposed background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SVG background.

See demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ym88y296wj

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this using Pseudo css.

```css
body{
  background:#ddd;
}
  .quote {
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.quote:before,
.quote:after {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.quote:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.quote:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-8.5deg);
  transform: skewY(-8.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
}

.quote {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 20% 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <h1>Triangular shapes</h1>
  <p>With 2 Pseudo Elements</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple background like this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 background:
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49.8%,#d2d2d2 50%) top right/30% 30%,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#d2d2d2 50%) bottom right/40% 40%,
  #a8a8a8;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```